# deinitialize() vs deallocate()

Tags: swift, pointers, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Why does the below code require me to manually use `unsafe_pointer.deinitialize(count: 1)` to deinitialize the instance?

The instance would be still alive within my memory if I only use the `unsafe_pointer.deallocate()`. What is the purpose of using `deallocate()` then?

Sorry in advance because I'm trying to learn MRC for the first time.

```
class Unsafe_Memory {
  var name = "Hello World"
  deinit {
    print("\(type(of: self)) is deinited and deallocated")
  }
}

let unsafe_pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unsafe_Memory> = .allocate(capacity: 1)

unsafe_pointer.pointee = Unsafe_Memory()
dump(unsafe_pointer.pointee)

unsafe_pointer.pointee.name = "Changed"
dump(unsafe_pointer.pointee)

unsafe_pointer.deinitialize(count: 1)
unsafe_pointer.deallocate()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `deinitialize` on any non-trivial types. According to the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawbufferpointer),

> A trivial type can be copied bit for bit with no indirection or
> reference-counting operations. Generally, native Swift types that do
> not contain strong or weak references or other forms of indirection
> are trivial, as are imported C structs and enums. Copying memory that
> contains values of nontrivial types can only be done safely with a
> typed pointer. Copying bytes directly from nontrivial, in-memory
> values does not produce valid copies and can only be done by calling a
> C API, such as memmove().

Calling `deinitialize` first uninitializes that memory, but as the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer/deinitialize(count:)) state, "After calling `deinitialize(count:)`, the memory is uninitialized, but still bound to the Pointee type".

After that, you free up that memory block by calling `deallocate()`, similar to `free()` from C. `deallocate()` can only be called on nontrivial types or uninitialized memory blocks.

If the type is trivial, you do not have to call `deinitialize`. It might be good to call `deinitialize` anyway in case somehow your type turns nontrivial in the future, and it does should not cost you anything to call it.

You can try by running your code without calling `deallocate`. The `deinit` block will still be executed, as `deinitialize` will run that block. However, that memory block is still occupied and not freed up until you call `deallocate`.